# Get the value closest to defined days for certain id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set that looks like this

```
id  | days
101 | 52
101 | 265
101 | 489
102 | 145
102 | 650
103 | 15
```

I want to only query row for each id that is closest to 200

So my expected output is

```
id  | days
101 | 265
102 | 145
103 | 15
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `row_number()` function which partitions by id and orders by `abs(200 - days)` - then you're ony interested in the first row of that set

```
with diffs
as
(
 select id, days, row_number() over(partition by id order by abs(200-days)) as row
 from data
)
select
  id,
  days
from diffs
where row = 1
```

Live example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5027597f1e23d78f862d59b36361f1f9

Comment: Might want to add either `days asc` or `days desc` to make a tie-breaker

Comment: @Charlieface `asc`is implicit when omitted

Comment: Yes I know that, I was just saying you should have *some* tie-breaker either ascending or descending

Comment: @Charlieface given the info we have (id and days) what tie break do you think we can have? The only way I see it is "first row in the dataset" which is what we have already.

Comment: Tie-break on positive or negative, which is what I was trying to say, sorry if it's not clear. If `ABS(200-210)` and `ABS(200-190)` both equal `10` then you need to tie-break them otherwise results are not deterministic. If yuo add `days desc` to the `order by` then it will always take the higher of those two, `days asc` will take the lower